# I need a sql query to view data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three table which are **cities**, **states** and **country**. Each table contains its respective columns as shown below:

```
cities{id,cityname,states_id}
states{id,statename,country_id}
country{id,name}
```

**Table Relations**

**cities** table contains `[states_id]`

**states** table contain `[country_id]`

If I select particular city, I would need to display `[cityname]`, `[statename]` and `[countryname]`

Comment: Just admin you are too lazy to google for it 5 min. Any tutorial would solve this problem for you if you only wanted. Basic SQL is not rocket science,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT cities.cityname, states.statename, countryname 
FROM cities JOIN
states ON cities.states_id = states.id JOIN
country ON states.country_id = country.id
WHERE cities.id=3;
```

Assuming 3 is the id of the city you are searching for...

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you provided:

```
SELECT ci.cityname
, st.statename
, cr.countryname
FROM Cities ci
JOIN States st ON ci.states_id = st.states_id
JOIN Country cr ON st.country_id = cr.country_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.cityname, s.statename, cy.name AS countryname
FROM cities c
INNER JOIN states s ON s.id = c.states_id
INNER JOIN country cy ON cy.id = s.country_id
WHERE c.id = 123
```

"123" is the city id you want to be informed about.